# Changing all values in a lambda/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a dictionary of a list of objects that looks like this

```
class Client
    {
        public int Hash { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
    var ClientsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Client>>();
```

I have no problem setting a single record value in the list

```
 ClientsDict[userId].First(a => a.Hash == hash).Active = true;
```

How do I do the inverse of that and set all the others in the list to false?

```
 ClientsDict[userId].All().Active = false; //cannot resolve symbol
```

Note: I wanna avoid a foreach

EDIT:

```
ClientsDict[userId].ForEach(a => a.Active = false); //this works
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid foreach?

Comment: Semantics.  A bulk edit should be as compact and concise as a single edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're mutating things you shouldn't be expressing it as a LINQ transformation. Just use a regular `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var client in ClientsDict[userId])
{
    client.Active = false;
}
```

You can also use the [`List<T>.ForEach` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx), but I would advise against it.

Comment: why would you advise against it?  How would you write this with .foreach?

Comment: I will accept your answer if you can answer the first part of my question, the second part I already answered

Comment: @LastTribunal The answer to your question is in the first sentence of the answer. Do not model mutation of state as an expression to be evaluated, explicitly use a loop statement to show state is being modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Where` LINQ method to express the opposite condition and loop over the resulting set:

```
foreach(var client in ClientsDict[userId].Where(c => c.Hash != hash))
{
    client.Active = false;
}
```

**EDIT**: the `ForEach()` method version for comparison:

```
ClientsDict[userId]
    .Where(c => c.Hash != hash)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => c.Active = false);
```

I'm usually not a fan of using the `ForEach()` method, but I have to admit that it doesn't look too bad here. That said, because the method is only available on `List<T>`, you're forced to call `.ToList()`.

For a more philosophical discussion on whether its use is a good idea or not, see here: [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

Comment: Yeah that looks good. I just thought you wanted to update all clients except one. That's what I understood from: *How do I do the __inverse__ of that and set all the __others__ in the list to false?*

Comment: Read the article, but its lame :)  Foreach looks more readable..haha

Comment: I'll accept your answer because you were most proactive

Comment: sorry bro, had to give it to the original guy